# How to create dynamic array in angular 4 reactive form and bind each field with input (formControlName)?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular4-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am working in angular 4 and facing an issue, I have created an array in form and bind each and every group with input field but when I fill the first field then it will automatically fill the second filed in browser but in form only value on one field will be  available.

dynamicArray.ts

```
addNewArrayForm : FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder : FormBuilder){}

ngOnInit() {
   this.addNewArrayForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      testArray : this.formBuilder.array([])
   });

   let arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
   let testArrayField = <FormArray>this.addNewArrayForm.controls['testArray'];
   for(let value of arrayValue){
      testArrayField.push(new FormControl(null));
   }

   checkValue(){
      console.log(this.addNewArrayForm.value);
      //Output 
      {
         testArray : ['1','12',null,null,null]
      }
   }
}
```

dynamicArray.html

```
<form [formGroup] = "addNewArrayForm">
   <div class="card" formArrayName="testArray" *ngIf="addNewArrayForm.controls['testArray'].value && (addNewArrayForm.controls['testArray'].value).length > 0">
      <div *ngFor="let value of addNewArrayForm.controls['testArray'].value; let x = index ">
         <input type="text" formControlName="{{x}}">
      </div>
      <div>
         <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="checkValue()">Click</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

You can check my issue on this link: https://angular-pdx2q2.stackblitz.io

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `trackBy` option on your ngFor directive to avoid the mess:

**template**

```
*ngFor="let value of addNewArrayForm.controls['testArray'].value; ...; trackBy: trackByFn"
```

**component**

```
trackByFn(index: number) {
  return index;
}
```

Forked **[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g559qn?file=src/app/app.component.html)**